# Using dotnet user-jwts in docker container (.NET 7 preview)

Tags: c#, .net, docker, asp.net-core

`dotnet user-jwts create` command [introduced in .NET 7 preview 5](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-dotnet-7-preview-5/#managing-development-time-jwts-with-dotnet-user-jwts) is very useful to create JWT tokens on a development machine. It works fine when I test the application locally but unfortunately it doesn’t work when I run the project in a docker container and I cannot run the above command to generate a JWT token on the docker container since it doesn’t have .NET SDK installed on it. I can install .NET SDK on the `final` image to bash to the container and get a JWT token but this is not an optimal solution.

Does anyone know a way to generate a JWT token when developing applications with a docker container?